# ¿Por qué no me retorna el valor booleano "false" en un párrafo HTML con la siguiente función? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, click, booleano

¡Hola! Como pueden observar, el siguiente código me retorna ambos valores *true* y *false* mediante un *console.log* sin problemas, aunque al intentar mostrarlo en un párrafo HTML, solamente salta el valor *true* si se cumple tal condición, pero nunca el valor booleano *false*. ¿Por qué será que ocurre esto solamente al querer usar un párrafo?

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(mostrarResultado);
function mostrarResultado(){
    year = Number($("#txtYear").val());
    let resultado1 = $("#pResultado").html(esBisiesto(year));
    let resultado2 = console.log(esBisiesto(year));
}

function esBisiesto(year){
    let bisiesto = false;
    if(year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0){
        bisiesto = true;
    }
    return bisiesto;
}
// console.log(esBisiesto(2400));
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <label for="txtYear">Ingresar año:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtYear">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminé concatenando *let bisiesto = false* con *""* y funcionó.

```
$("#btnIngresar").click(mostrarResultado);
function mostrarResultado(){
    year = Number($("#txtYear").val());
    let resultado1 = $("#pResultado").html(esBisiesto(year));
    let resultado2 = console.log(esBisiesto(year));
}

function esBisiesto(year){
    let bisiesto = false + ""; // --> ARREGLO <-- 
    if(year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0){
        bisiesto = true;
    }
    return bisiesto;
}
// console.log(esBisiesto(2400));
```

Comment: No podías inyectar la respuesta de la función `esBisiesto()` en el **DOM** porque para poder hacerlo necesitas que el valor a insertar sea un `string` cosa que los valores booleanos no son. Al hacer `let bisiesto = false + "";` estás forzando una conversión implícita a `string`, por eso puedes inyectarlo en el **DOM**